# Parse Exception EOF Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-pig

Query:

```
hive> CREATE TABLE GREENTAXI(VendorID INT, pick_up_date DATE,drop_date DATE,Flag CHAR(1),rate_code INT, pick_up_long STRING,pick_up_lat STRING,drop_off_long STRING,drop_off_lat STRING,passenger_count INT,trip_distance DECIMAL,fare_amount DECIMAL,Extra DECIMAL,Tax DECIMAL,Tip DECIMAL,Tolls INT,Fee INT,Surcharge DECIMAL,total_amount DECIMAL,payment_type INT,trip_type INT)COMMENT 'Data about Green NYC Taxi for the year 2016-Jan’ ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

I get this error. Please advise

[image]

Comment: Change the closing quote near `2016-Jan`.

Comment: Looks like it is character encoding. Use a simple text editor and try again.

Comment: Please replace the picture with text.

Comment: I have replaced the quote after Jan with another quote and it worked

Answer (score -1):

Looks like some character encoding problem. Use a simple editor. Tried this and worked:

```
CREATE TABLE greentaxi 
  ( 
     vendorid        INT, 
     pick_up_date    DATE, 
     drop_date       DATE, 
     flag            CHAR(1), 
     rate_code       INT, 
     pick_up_long    STRING, 
     pick_up_lat     STRING, 
     drop_off_long   STRING, 
     drop_off_lat    STRING, 
     passenger_count INT, 
     trip_distance   DECIMAL, 
     fare_amount     DECIMAL, 
     extra           DECIMAL, 
     tax             DECIMAL, 
     tip             DECIMAL, 
     tolls           INT, 
     fee             INT, 
     surcharge       DECIMAL, 
     total_amount    DECIMAL, 
     payment_type    INT, 
     trip_type       INT 
  ) 
comment 'Data about Green NYC Taxi for the year 2016-Jan'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: As @franklinsijo commented, the issue here (the only issue) is the closing quote of the comment (`’`) that should be changed to `'`

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz, What is the reason for downvote? You are wrong (about the only issue), look at the error message. It says character 487. I tried this code and made it work by only changing the last character. Take your downvote back dude.

Comment: Typo is not a "character encoding problem". No change was needed other than the replacement of that single character. "<EOF> not supported here" since the comment's openning qualifier was left unmatched. The file ended sooner than expected.

Comment: It's the end of the text. The parser is looking for the matching `'` and gets to the end of the text before he finds one.

Comment: Line 1, character 487